# How to rework TYPO3 8 AbstractViewHelper for TYPO3 9.5

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, view-helpers, typo3-9.x

we have a class called AmazMenu.php which extends from the class AbstractViewHelper. It does some stuff on 600 lines of code but now the Baseclass got removed. its a [documented breaking change](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-82414-RemoveCMSBaseViewHelperClasses.html) but i cant figure out what approach to use from now on and how to refactor the class used stuff like:

```
public function initializeArguments()
private function recursiveTree($tree, $maxDepth = 0, $depth = 0, $parentIsActive = false)
private function renderTree()
public function render()
```

because i guess if the Baseclass gets removed also the directory ViewHelpers is gone - so the logic handled by our ViewHelper has to get implemented somewhere else - but were and by what concept?

help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use the AbstractClass of the template engine: `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper` instead. That's the change for TYPO3 itself in most cases as you can see here: https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/54946/4/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/ViewHelpers/AvatarViewHelper.php

Also follow the migration steps, don't use the `render()` method anymore, but use `renderStatic()`. This is also documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html#renderstatic-method

Comment: thanks alot! and what happens with, for example, $this->objectManager->get('ConfigurationManagerNamespace') the fluid core baseclass doesent provide that - is there a general way of getting those instances?

Comment: Might be possible to use Dependency Injection. If that's not working one can use `GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ObjectManager::class)->get('ConfigurationManagerNamespace')`